# Why can't I view cout in debug watch window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

While I run this in VS:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    ostringstream local;
    auto cout_buff = cout.rdbuf();
    cout.rdbuf(local.rdbuf());
    cout << "some message";
    cout.rdbuf(cout_buff);
    cout << "back to default buffer\n";
    cout << "local contetn:" << local.str() << endl;
}
```

I wanna see how `cout` internally changes, trying to add `cout` in *Watch Window*, but I got `identifier "cout" is undefined`. How come?

[image]

Comment: I've always wondered this, since VS 2008.  I've always had to use `OutputDebugStringA` to get the output to the debug window.

Comment: Its name is `std::cout`. Changing that might help.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's not working. :D

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you for telling me that. :D So it doesn't have this feature now. :D

Comment: As of VS 2017, the `OutputDebugStringA` is still needed to output to the debug window.

Comment: Maybe this is a *definition* thing.  `cout` displays to a *console*.  The debug window is not a console.  And in GUI/Windows mode, there are no console windows (unless you specifically create one); thus the output from `cout` doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: A nice feature would be able to tie or redirect `cout` to the debug window.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The question is not about where cout prints, it's about visualizing the internal data members of the cout object.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to speculate *why* it doesn't find `cout`, but it is a workaround to create a local alias and *watch* that:

```
int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    auto& cout = std::cout;
    // ...
```